# Documentation tool that allows building documentation from tests

Tags: java, testing, documentation

I have made a couple dozens of tests for a legacy system I was handed over.

They generally test/describe some high level feature of the system, and I generally include in the test file itself a little comment about that feature. In this way, I both have a regression test suite and I'm compiling knowledge of the system in a single place, so others in the future don't have to lose all the time I lost trying to understand the (up to now) undocumented system.

Now, I was looking for some tool that would allow me to organize and see the high level features in a simpler way than having to look up to the test files. If it allowed a tag system, even better.

I have heard of Fitnesse but it doesn't look to fit really in what I'm looking for. I'm not looking for a tool to bridge the communication between the client and developers.

This project is coded in Java.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you moved the documentation from the unit tests to the classes you are testing, you could use either standard JavaDoc or [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).

Comment: I am already using JavaDoc for documenting the classes of my system. But that will only document the method signature and not much more. My tests are system-wide tests, testing the whole system, it's not like I can pass the documentation from the tests to the classes under test.

Comment: You can run JavaDoc on your test classes instead if that makes sense for your application. JavaDoc can do a lot more than just output method signatures. Take a look at the [Doclet Introduction](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/javadoc/overview.html) to see some examples. You can basically render your own template any way you want to see it using either their standard tags or your own custom tags. And you get access to all the AST data that the JavaDoc application uses to generate the method signatures. JavaDoc is actually quite versatile if you need it to be.

Comment: I'll check it. I wasn't aware of JavaDoc's versatility.